# Why C++ forbids new T[n](arg...)?

Tags: c++

This question seems ancient (since C++98), but a quick search didn't lead me to an answer.

```
std::size_t n = 100;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> data(new int[n]); // ok, uninitialized
std::unique_ptr<int[]> data(new int[n]()); // ok, value-initialized
std::unique_ptr<int[]> data(new int[n](5)); // not allowed, but why?
```

What's the rationale behind this restriction, some UDTs cannot be default constructed, so those types cannot be used with new[].

Please don't go astray to suggesting something like `std::vector` or just say that's how the standard defines it, everyone knows that, but I want to know the reason why `new T[n](arg...)` is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: You supplied invalid syntax and asked "what's the rationale behind this restriction"... What is the "restriction" in your opinion? What do you suggest that syntax should do?

Answer (score 3):

The first part of the answer to "why is it forbidden" is almost tautological: because it is not allowed by the standard. I know you probably don't like such an answer, but that's the nature of the beast, sorry.

And why should it be allowed anyway? What would it mean? In your very very very simple case, initializing every `int` with a specific value is fairly reasonable. But then again, for normal (statically allocated) array initialization, the rule is that each element in the right hand side `{}` is passed to an element of the left hand side array, with extra elements getting default-initialization treatment. Ie,

```
int data[n] = {5};
```

would only initialize the first element with `5`.

But let's look at another example, which isn't even very contrived, which shows that what you ask for doesn't really make a lot of sense in a general context.

```
struct Foo {
    int a,b,c,d;
    Foo(int a=0, int b=0, int c=0, int d=0)
        : a(a), b(b), c(c), d(d) {}
};

...


Foo *f = new Foo[4](1,2,3,4); // <-- what does this mean?!?!
```

Should there be four `Foo(1,2,3,4)`s? Or `[Foo(1,2,3,4), Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]`? Or maybe `[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)]`? Or why not `[Foo(1,2,3), Foo(4), Foo(), Foo()]`? What if one of `Foo`'s arguments was rvalue reference or something? There are just soooo many cases in which there is no obvious Right Thing that the compiler should do. Most of the examples I just gave have valid use cases, and there isn't one that's clearly better than the others.

---

PS: You can achieve what you want with eg

```
std::vector<int> data(n, 5);
```

Comment: I'd expect it to be four `Foo(1,2,3,4)`, it's the only reasonable choice if such syntax is ever allowd. For `[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)]` we have `new Foo[4]{1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: `it's the only reasonable choice` That is your opinion. I disagree, and I think you would be hard pressed to achieve consensus among programmers.

Comment: rvalue reference is a good point, though the design decision is since C++98.

Comment: @Jamboree The inconsistency you already saw between `new Foo[4](1,2,3,4)` and `new Foo[4]{1,2,3,4}` seems like a strong argument *against* your expected meaning of the syntax to me.

Comment: @hvd I think so. I was too imaginative.

Comment: "with extra elements getting default-initialization" - No, the extra elements are value-initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> some UDTs don't even have a default ctor, so those types cannot be used with new[]

I'm not sure what you mean by this. E.g. `int` does not have a default constructor. However, you can initialize it as `new int(3)` or as `new int[n]()`, as you already know. The event that takes place here is called *initialization*. Initialization can be carried out by *constructors*, but that's just a specific kind of initialization applicable to class types only. `int` is not a class type and constructors are completely inapplicable to `int`. So, you should not be even mentioning constructors with regard to `int`.

As for `new int[n](5)`... What did you expect to happen in this case? C++ does not support such syntax for array initialization. What did you want it to mean? You have `n` array elements and only one initializer. How are you proposing to initialize `n` array elements and only one initializer? Use value `5` to initialize *each* array element? But C++ never had such multi-initialization. Even the modern C++ doesn't.

You seem to have adopted this "multi-initialization" interpretation of `new int[n](5)` syntax as the one and only "obviously natural" way for it to behave. However, this is not necessarily that clear-cut. Historically C++ language (and C language) followed a different philosophy with regard to initializers that are "smaller" or "shorter" than the aggregate being initialized. Historically the language used the explicitly specified initializers to initialize the sub-objects at the beginning of the aggregate, while the rest of the sub-objects got default-initialized (sticking to C++98 terminology). From this point of view, you can actually see the `()` initializer in `new int[n]()` not as your "multi-initializer", but rather as an initializer only for the very first element of the array. Meanwhile, the rest of the elements get default-initialized (producing the same effect as `()` would). Granted, one can argue that the above logic usually applies to `{ ... }` initializers, not to `(...)` initializers, but nevertheless this general design principle is present in the language.

Comment: I edit that sentence to make it clearer. Yes I do expect `new int[n](5)` to initialize each element of the array with value 5. And C++ does have multi-initialization, if `T` is a UDT that defines a default ctor, that ctor will be called n times.

Comment: why? even `() ` is a single initializer, just without args.

Comment: @Jamboree: Default constructor, specifically? Default constructor is special, becuase it is called "by default". But in this case you need non-default constructor with a specific initializer. C++ has no such feature as channeling a specific initializer to multiple array elements.

Comment: @Jamboree: `()` is given special treatment. It simply orders the compiler to perform default initialization (C++98) or value initialization (C++03) on all array elements. But once you specify any "non-empty" explicit initializer, C++ will not help you to channel it into each array element.

Comment: Of course we know C++ doesn't have the feature currently, but I want to know why. Is it because no one proposed it? is it because it's potentially dangerous? ...I want to know the technical reason why we don't have it today.

Comment: @Jamboree: I added a few words to my answer above.

Comment: "but rather as an initializer only for the very first element of the array" I think it's not true, the `()` initializer in `new int[n]()` value-initialized the *whole* array, not just the first element.

Comment: @Jamboree: You are missing the point. One more time: C++ language (just like C), follows **all-or-nothing** approach to initialization. Which means that when you initialize (using any method) only one (first) element of the array, all remaining elements are *automatically* value-initialized for you. For this reason, you can think of `()` as something that *explicitly* value-initializes only one (first) element of the array, while the rest of the elements get value-initialized *implicitly*, in accordance with the above all-or-nothing rule.

Comment: @Jamboree: For example, when you do `int a[10] = { 0 }`, then only `a[0]` is initialized by that explicit `0` you specified. The rest of `a` also becomes zeroed out, but that initialization is done by implicit value-initialization process, not by your `0`.

Comment: That's wrong (this could be a little pedantic). Please have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), "3) If T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized". What you had in mind is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: @Jamboree: No, this is not "wrong". And I don't see how what you linked shows that I'm "wrong". So far I simply said that one can see it this way: the `()` value-initializes the *first* array element *explicitly*, while the rest of the array gets value-initialized *implicitly*. The end result is that all array elements get value-initialized. The standard says "...each element of the array is value-initialized", which is exactly the same thing. So, where do you see the contradiction between what I said and what the standard says?

Comment: the way you see it is not how the standard describes it, admittedly both lead to the same end result. `()` is not for the first element, but the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `int[n](5)` would even mean. `int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}` is perfectly well-defined, however.

I'm going to assume you mean for `int[n](...)` to construct each array element in the same way with the given arguments. Your use case for such a syntax is for data types without a default constructor, but I posit that you don't actually solve that use case: that for many (most?) arrays of such types, each object needs to be constructed differently.

Answer (score 0):

The original expectation is to allow `new T[n](arg…)` to call `T(arg…)` to initialize each element.

It turns out that people don't even agree on what `new T[n](arg…)` would mean.

I gather some good points from the ansnwers and comments, here's the summary:

- Inconsistent meaning. parenthesized initializer is used to initialize the object, in case of an array, the only viable one is `()` which default initializes the array and its elements. Give `T[n](arg…)` a new meaning will conflict with the current meaning of parenthesized initializer.
- No general way to channel the args. Consider a type `T` with ctor `T(int, Ref&, Rval&&)`, and the usage `new T[n](++i, ref, Rval{})`. If the args is supplied literally (i.e. call `T(++i, ref, Rval{})` for each), `++i` will be called multiple times. If the args is supplied through some temporaries, how can you decide `ref` will pass by reference, while `Rval{}` will pass as prvalue?

In short, the syntax seems plausible but doesn't actually make sense and is not generally implementable.